# Condition CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

It is a question about strategy to take and to resolve my doubts about the idea I have.

What I want is to allow CORS requests, ie. Access-Control-Allow-Origin to be dependent on environment type I have. So here is my cors headers:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://siteone.com');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization, access-control-allow-origin');
  next();
});
```

But what I want is conditional logic like this:

```
const ACAOSite = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production' ? 'https://siteone.com' : 'https://sitetwo.com';

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', ACAOSite);
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization, access-control-allow-origin');
  next();
});
```

Is it good practice though? Is there another way to do that? Also, I don't want to allow every site and use *, I want to be selective what site I want to allow.

Comment: you might want to externalize the domains, that are allowed, in some configuration file other than it is all ok.

Comment: Controlling the allowed origins instead of using a wildcard is generally good practice. What I would suggest is using something like [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) for environment configuration instead of having it in code though.

Answer (score 0):

Use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) or a config file to set your allowed origins.

The same way you would have different configurations for your database credentials on test/production read from .env (using [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)) or a config file that can be modified on the server.

For instance, if your .env file contains:

```
allowed_origins=https://siteone.com
```

Then your code would be something like this:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', process.env.allowed_origins);
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization, access-control-allow-origin');
  next();
});
```

You can also have more than one origin comma separated e.g.

```
allowed_origins=https://siteone.com, https://siteone-server2.com
```

Comment: This reputable documentation source says "Only a single origin can be specified. If the server supports clients from multiple origins, it must return the origin for the specific client making the request."  Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin#directives